# Submit form with jquery says it works but it doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to submit a form using jquery so that the page doesn't refresh when it submits. my code is:

```
<div class="subscribe">
<p><span>Subscrever à Newsletter<span><br/>
<form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nwsltrname" value="Nome"/><br/>
        <input type="email" name="nwsltrmail" value="Email" required/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="nwsltrmailx" value=""/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="nwsltradd" value="Subscrever" />
</form></p>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(".subscribe input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    var siteurl = window.location.href;
    var nwsltrname = $("input[name='nwsltrname']").val();
    var nwsltrmail = $("input[name='nwsltrmail']").val();
    var nwsltrmailx = $("input[name='nwsltrmailx']").val();
    var dataString = "&nwsltrname="+ nwsltrname + "&nwsltrmail=" + nwsltrmail + "&nwsltrmailx=" + nwsltrmailx;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: siteurl,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            alert("it works!");
        }
    });
    return false;
 });
```

So the problem is the form does not submit but it still alerts "it works!"

what's wrong with my code? How can I make it submit the form?

Comment: dataString  needs to be a JSON construct

Comment: so... what should be written there?

Comment: AJAX form submission does not literally submit the form in the traditional, HTML sense. It suppresses normal submission and instead routes data through an XHR request. You can veryify if this is happening via your browser's network console.

Comment: i know that it's not happening. this form makes a new entry in a list in the backoffice of this website and when i use this jquery code, the entry is not added to that list. i need this to work

Comment: Something is posted to the url and it responds with a HTTP 200 (OK) status code, which is why you see the message. If it didn't work, check on the server side what happened (did you get incorrect data?) and respond accordingly by returning, for instance, 403 bad request if some required arguments are missing.

Comment: Your code is incomplete so. What is happening with the AJAX data? Where's the server side script?

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the network tab. Look at the request you are actually making. Look at the response you are actually getting.

Comment: You need to be sure where the problem lies. If the alert is firing then the request IS being sent. As @GolezTrol says, the problem would appear instead to be with your server-side code not doing what you think it should. That is a different matter from the form not being submitted.

Comment: What is the server side language? It is likely that the server is responding with a HTTP 200 code, this means that the server has responded fine i.e. File exists and has been executed. The server side script will need to validate input, check that it has been entered into data (if needed) and  then determine the correct status code to return. Either HTTP 200 (OK) or any of many other scenarios. **Reference:** http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: When the Ajax call is returned it does NOT update the current page you are on. If you want the current page to get new data you need to add it to the page. If you want the page to refresh, DO NOT use Ajax, just use a traditional post.

Comment: @Utkanos if i leave out the jquery and just submit the form normally, reloading the page, it does work so i think that should mean that the server side script is correct, right?

Comment: Please add relevant part of the server side script. Otherwise, this question is useless for you and future readers.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴛᴜʀғɪʟɪᴘɪᴀᴋ so you mean that you can't see anything wrong with the code I posted?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
data: {  
        nwsltrname: nwsltrname,
        nwsltrmail: nwsltrmail,
        nwsltrmailx: nwsltrmailx
      }
```

And this will create the correct parameters on the server. All that the alert does is to say that the service-side function has returned. Not that it has processed correctly.

Also, look at the comments above.

Bon chance

Comment: The value of the `data` property when calling `$.ajax()` can be a string; it's just used exactly as passed as the query string for the request in that case.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGrist, I appreciate that.  However, it does provide that return in a form which is easier to debug/process unless the back-end server explicitly recognises the GET format.

Answer (score 0):

The success will work even if you have error in server code... so add a response param to the success function then alert it to know the server response .. then you can debug the issue .. change code like below...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: siteurl,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: the alert i get is the complete html of the page, like <!DOCTYPE html><head> etc etc

Comment: Are you submitting to the correct url... siteurl ... window.location.href is the current page url ... change url to the page you written the saving code

Comment: Or if you written the saving code in the same page then do a isset($_POST) check and execute the required code block

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".subscribe input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    var siteurl = window.location.href;
    var nwsltrname = $("input[name='nwsltrname']").val();
    var nwsltrmail = $("input[name='nwsltrmail']").val();
    var nwsltrmailx = $("input[name='nwsltrmailx']").val();
    var dataString = "&nwsltrname="+ nwsltrname + "&nwsltrmail=" + nwsltrmail + "&nwsltrmailx=" + nwsltrmailx;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: siteurl,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            alert("it works!");
        }
    });
    return false;
 });
```

above request should be written as,

```
$(".subscribe input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    var siteurl = window.location.href;
    var nwsltrname = $("input[name='nwsltrname']").val();
    var nwsltrmail = $("input[name='nwsltrmail']").val();
    var nwsltrmailx = $("input[name='nwsltrmailx']").val();
    var dataString = {
                         Nwsltrname = nwsltrname,
                         Nwsltrmail = nwsltrmail,
                         Nwsltrmailx = nwsltrmailx
                     };
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: siteurl,
        dataType: "json"
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            alert("it works!");
        }
    });
    return false;
 });
```

**Note:** Remember your request type is post so data will be sent in the request body not header. Success function will return you the data.

Comment: Take a look at the **@Peter Smith** answer and the comment below.

Comment: something's wrong with this because I copied it directly from here and now none of the code in the js file is working. all the { and ( are closed...

Comment: the error in your code was the lack of a "," after dataType: "json" but even with that fixed it's not submitting and now i don't even get the "it works!" alert...

Comment: if possible can you share your server side method which you are intended to post the data to